# Is it possible to mock the low-level "call" in Solidity (0.8.9) using Waffle/Chai?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, chai

I am using Hardhat with Waffle/Chai assertions.

I am trying to set up mock contracts from waffle [docs](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mock-contract.html#usage).

```
await mockContract.mock.call.returns(true, ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(""));
```

is not working for me. How do I test eth transfers conducted in my solidity contracts that use `.call`?

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh) and my [Foundry Template](https://github.com/paulrberg/foundry-template) and you won't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: Ah didn't realize Foundry had a way around this. Will check it out, thanks